# How to use grep command for count extended ASCII characters

Tags: linux, grep, ascii, extended-ascii

I have a file which contains Inverted exclamation mark, I want to count number of occurrences of these inverted exclamation marks using Linux grep command.

I have tried hex representation of this character as follows. but it is returning complete file , not exactly the lines which are matching this text.

```
grep -v "["$'\xA1'"]" K2345061.005
```

Thanks in advance for sharing any idea on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your grep supports the `-P` flag for PCRE regex syntax, you can use that:

```
$ echo -e '\xa1Ay caramba!' > /tmp/a1.dat
$ grep -P '\xa1' /tmp/a1.dat 
¡Ay caramba!
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep -v` is used to list files which do **not** match. Remove the `-v` option.

Comment: i have removed the -v option, now it does not return any results